# google bigtable hbase getValueArray vs CellUtil.cloneValue

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, hbase, bigtable

Would I be correct to say that, if I'm trying to get the value of a Cell as a byte array, I should always use CellUtil.cloneValue? Or is it safe to use getValueArray? Is there any more efficient ways (as cloneValue seems to copy the array)

So far, whenever I have read from bigtable I've used getValueArray without any issue. Seems like the internal implementation of the BigtableAbstractTable uses https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/read/RowCell,  just happens to have the value array exactly equal to the value. However, the documentation for Cell seems to suggest that this is not always the case, and behavior is not guaranteed in the future. Should I change all the usage of getValueArray to cloneValue?

Answer (score 1):

`cloneValue` is fine for small values.  You can add a check to ensure that the value length (`cell.getValueLength()`) is the same as `cell.getValueArray().length`.

Cloud Bigtable ought to provide a utility that does this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1767

Comment: Thanks @Solomon! I will add this check. Is it correct to say that it is unsafe to just use `getValueArray` or `getColumn/FamilyArray` functions without doing this check?

Comment: It's definitely safer to add that check.  The Cloud Bigtable client doesn't make any guarantees that this behavior will continue in the future.